# How to download a GIF from firebase and save it to a drawable?

Tags: android

Can someone take me out of this complexity.
I am searching for code that downloading GIF from
firebase and store it in internal storage or draw able and then to show those downloaded GIF in intent activity.

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


Intent intent = new Intent(MoreGifsActivity.this, GifsClick.class);
                      intent.putExtra("Activitycheck", "Two");
                        intent.putExtra("Position", imagesurl.get(position));                       startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: you can't store in drawable.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) since it will make loading images easier, and it will cache them for you which saves a lot of trouble.

Glide can even help you downloading the file straight from the url.

### Example

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.test);
Glide.with(this).load("url or local path").
                diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE).into(imageView);
```

Now the only thing you would need to pass to your second activity would be the url to the same file, and Glide can load it for you again.

Note: There is something in glide that I saw called `asGif` which might be worth looking into. Not sure what works right now, since I haven't had need of Glide for a while.

Comment: this is for downloading images where as i need to download GIF from fire base if i use this code i don't get my required work

Comment: And secondly                                                      ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.test); This is for what ?

Comment: and i use your above code i get diskCacheStrategy and source problem ..how i can solve it